# wordpress start date end date events

Tags: wordpress, date, templates, events

I'm looking to simply add start date/end date functionality to custom post templates. Is there a way to do this?

It's using Wordpress. There is this plugin, but it doesn't seem to display them on the front end.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimalistic-event-manager/

Comment: You could use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). It uses it's own functions to display the custom values, ie. `the_field( 'start_date' )`.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: ACF (like Michael said) would be best option and it offers nice option to expand in future if needed. Very flexible

Comment: thankyou for the answer to this. unfortunately the date format seems to be wrong. does anyone have an idea how to change the date format to something like 'Friday, January 24th'?

Comment: is there a way to have a custom field not show up if a date isn't actually entered? it seems to be popping up with 1970 if the date isnt actually selected...